# Display notification after specific frame loads

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am creating a Google Extension that will display a simple text notification immediately after a specific frame loads in our company's web-based applicant tracking system.

The frame loads via JavaScript after clicking a specific button on the webpage:

```html
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="formletter();;TrackActionClick(7516);return false;" class="actionIcon icon-med icon-highlight MailAction icon-Mail" title="Letter"></a>
```

This is the URL of the frame that I am trying to get to trigger the notification: `https://www2.pcrecruiter.net/pcrbin/bmail.exe`

I am having trouble getting a notification to display after clicking the button and loading the frame (nothing happens currently).

**manifest.json**

```json
{
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "name": "Bulk Email Reminder",
    "description": "This extension provides a reminder for AE's to use SparkPost when sending a bulk email",
    "version": "1.0",
    "icons": {
        "16": "logo.png"
    },

    "permissions": [
    "notifications"
    ],

    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["*://*.pcrecruiter.net/pcrbin/bmail.exe"],
            "match_about_blank": true,
            "js": ["myscript.js"]
        }
    ]
}
```

**myscript.js**

```
// Create a simple text notification:
var notification = webkitNotifications.createNotification(
    'Hello!', // notification title
    'Lorem ipsum...' // notification body text
);

// Then show the notification.
notification.show();
```

Comment: Please define 'APS'. Also, a Chrome extension sounds like a bad solution to this. Do your users always use Chrome? Can you ensure they will definitely have the plugin?

Comment: Hey Michael, thanks very much for the feedback. APS = applicant tracking system (the web-based recruiting application our office uses).  Our users always use Chrome, yes. And I can ensure they will definitely have the plugin (it's a smaller company with about 20 employees). If there is an alternative strategy for doing this outside of a Google Extension, I am all ears. Thanks again.

Comment: I would suggest that you read the [Chrome extension overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview) (and perhaps along with the pages linked from the overview). The [architecture section](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch) has overall architecture information which should help your understanding of how things are generally organized/done.

Comment: Hey Makyen, I have edited the original question accordingly and have included my code for reference. My apologies for not being more clear in the original question. I've shifted focus to displaying a notification after a frame loads, which seems more of an obtaininable goal. Thanks

Comment: @Scott, BTW: If you want a specific person to be notified of your comment, you need to include their ID in your comment with an `@` in front of it. For instance, for me it would be `@Makyen`. If you do this as the first thing in your comment, the system will provide auto-complete suggestions from those who have already posted comments on that answer/question. The original poster of the answer/question on which you are commenting will always be notified. This [meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43020/271271) has more information.

Comment: @Scott, Thank you for adding code. Doing so limits the question to something that is answerable.

Comment: @Makyen, thanks very much for your assistance and for the answer you provided! I appreciate your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Detect navigation in background script, not via a content script

You are not manipulating the content of the webpage. You are just using the loading of the content script to detect that a particular URL is being loaded in a frame.  Thus, it would be better to just directly detect in a background script that a matching URL has been loaded in a frame. You can do this with the [`chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation#event-onCompleted) event, which can be [filtered for specific URLs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/events#type-UrlFilter), so you only get events for matching URLs.

To generate the notification, you can use [`chrome.notifications`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/notifications).

The background script is only listening to events, so it can be an [Event Page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages).

To do this, your extension can look like:

*manifest.json*:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Bulk Email Reminder",
    "description": "This extension provides a reminder for AE's to use SparkPost when sending a bulk email",
    "version": "1.0",
    "icons": {
        "16": "logo.png"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "notifications",
        "webNavigation"
    ],
    "background":{
        "scripts":[
            "background.js"
        ],
        "persistent": false
    }
}
```

*background.js*:

```js
chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted.addListener(function(details){
    //You can check that details.frameId !== 0 if you only want to
    //  notify when in an iframe and *not* when loaded as the main frame.
    if(details.frameId !==0){
        //This is not the base frame (i.e. it is in an iframe)
        let options =  {
            type:'basic',
            iconUrl:'logo.png',
            title:'Hello!',
            message:'Lorem ipsum...'
        }
        chrome.notifications.create(options);
    }
}, {
    url: [    
        {urlMatches: '^[^:]*:(?://)?(?:[^/]*\\.)?pcrecruiter.net/pcrbin/bmail\\.exe$'}
        //,{urlMatches: '^[^:]*:(?://)?(?:[^/]*\\.)?' + 'example.com' + '/.*$'} //for testing
    ]
});
```

Note: Using URL filtering is something of a pain. Without using a regular expression, there is no good way to match a domain and all sub-domains, with or without a file, while being sure to not match URLs which spoof the desired URL. Thus, my preference is to use a `urlMatches` regular expression which will definitively only match the URL you desire.

## Loading a content script into an iframe

If you are actually going to manipulate the contents of the iframe, or get data from it, then you actually want to load a content script into the iframe. Another reason that you might want to use this method is that it will present a different [permissions warning](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/permission_warnings) to the user.  Using `webNavigation` may result in the user getting a warning that the extension will have access to: "Access your browsing activity". Using a content script will only notify about the specific websites which you have specified as matching URLs for the the content script.

If you want to have your content script loaded into iframes then you need to specify [`"all_frames": true`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#all_frames) in your [*manifest.json*](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest) [`content_scripts`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#registration) entry.

In this case, you do not want to be matching blank frames, so having [`"match_about_blank": true,`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#match_about_blank) is not appropriate.

In addition, `webkitNotifications` was deprecated and removed from Chrome some time ago. Given that you are writing a Chrome extension, it would be best to use [`chrome.notifications`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/notifications). However, `chrome.notifications` is not an API available to content scripts. Thus, you will need to have a background script to which you send a message from your content script, using `chrome.runtime.sendMessage()`, instructing it to create the notification with [`chrome.notifications.create()`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/notifications#method-create). Given that your background script is only handling events (messages), it can be an [Event Page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages).

Thus, your extension could look like:

*manifest.json*:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Bulk Email Reminder",
    "description": "This extension provides a reminder for AE's to use SparkPost when sending a bulk email",
    "version": "1.0",
    "icons": {
        "16": "logo.png"
    },

    "permissions": [
        "notifications"
    ],

    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["*://*.pcrecruiter.net/pcrbin/bmail.exe"],
            "all_frames": true,
            "js": ["myscript.js"]
        }
    ]
}
```

*background.js*:

```js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message,sender,sendResponse){
    if(message.type === 'createNotification'){
        chrome.notifications.create(message.id,message.options);
    }
});
```

*myscript.js*:

```js
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
    type:'createNotification',
    //id: '', //You do not need to specify this, but can if desired
    options: {
        type:'basic',
        iconUrl:'logo.png',
        title:'Hello!',
        message:'Lorem ipsum...'
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks for the answer! The `"all_frames"` entry ended up being the missing piece, as you suggested. I changed the myscript.js code to a one-line alert for the sake of simplicity, and that did it:`alert("Don't forget to use SparkPost!");`Thanks again!